# Как правильно расчитать координаты вывода спрайтов относительно расширения экрана девайса?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, спрайт, dpi

Имеется картинка (background) 480х800. Мне надо вывести bitmap поверх бэкгроунда с определенными координатами. Проблема в том, что на девайсах с разрешением 480х800 выводится правильно, а на других соответственно со смещением. Все картинки находятся в res/drawable директории. Позже планирую сделать все картинки разных размеров и раскидать по своим директориям (hdpi, ldpi и т.д.)

Размеры экрана и прочие переменные я получаю следующим кодом (в коментах их значения):

Тут брал эмулятор 480х800:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();

frameWidth = metrics.widthPixels; // 480
frameHeight = metrics.heightPixels; // 800 
xDpi = metrics.xdpi; // 240
yDpi = metrics.ydpi; // 240
scaleFactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; // 1.5
```

Тут брал 720х1280:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();

frameWidth = metrics.widthPixels; // 720
frameHeight = metrics.heightPixels; // 1232 
xDpi = metrics.xdpi; // 164.75676
yDpi = metrics.ydpi; // 165.03554
scaleFactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; // 1.0
```

По какому принципу нужно производить расчет координат вывода чтоб спрайты/битмапы отображались одинаково на всех девайсов относительно бэкграунда/других объектов/друг друга?

Для наглядности, добавил скриншоты с двух эмуляторов:
[image: 480х800]

[image: 720х1280]

Comment: По вашей теме отличная статья https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/136802/

Comment: @СергейГрушин Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю на собственный вопрос:

Допустим нам надо вывести спрайт на экране к координате 140х200. Расчитываем все относительно базовой картинки, которая находится в drawable-mdpi директории. Я за основу взял изображение 480х800. Теперь вычисляем процентально координаты X и Y:

```
    procX=480/140; // =3.42857142857 
    procY=800/200; // =4
```

Когда мы знаем процент соотношения точек и знаем ширину и высоту экрана (наши переменные frameWidth, frameHeight), мы можем вычислить координаты
на экране с другим разрешением:

```
    x=frameWidth/procX;
    y=frameHeight/procY;
```

Проверяем относительно экрана 720х1280:

```
    x=720/procX; // = 210
    y=1280/procY // = 320
```

Может этот метод и неправильный, но вполне рабочий.